# Excel Macro - How to merge 2 Different Function of Macros

Tags: vba

I am new to here and excel macro beginner. I need help for how to..join below macros into 1. 
- The function of 1st macro is to move the cell to next row once specific cell is entered
- The function of second sub-macro is enter the timestamp when last specific cell of row is entered.

Thank you...Yanto

The macros:

1st Macro(main)

```vba
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Whoa

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
Target.Offset(, 1).Select
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
Target.Offset(, 1).Select
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then
Target.Offset(, 1).Select
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(4)) Is Nothing Then
Target.Offset(1, -3).Select
End If
End If
Letscontinue:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

2nd Macro(sub)

```vba
Private Sub Worksheet_Change1(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D3000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
Dim lc As Long

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
lc = Cells(Target.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If lc = 1 Then
Cells(Target.Row, lc + 2) = Now()
ElseIf lc > 1 Then
Cells(Target.Row, lc + 1) = Now()
End If
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the sub macro name in your main macro like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'''''''''''''''''some code''''''''''''''''''''
    call Worksheet_Change1(Target)
'''''''''''''''''some code''''''''''''''''''''
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. I did try that method earlier But it is still giving me error. Please do you mind to put the complete code sand test it for me. Thanks...Yanto

Answer (score 0):

Friend,
Please ignore my comment. I managed to get the codes merged with exec output as expected. Thanks again

The codes:
    Option Explicit

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo Whoa

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
Target.Offset(, 1).Select
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
Target.Offset(, 1).Select
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then
Target.Offset(, 1).Select
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(4)) Is Nothing Then
Target.Offset(1, -3).Select
End If
End If

Call Worksheet_Change1(Target)

Letscontinue:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Letscontinue

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change1(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D3000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
Dim lc As Long
With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
lc = Cells(Target.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If lc = 1 Then
Cells(Target.Row, lc + 2) = Now()
ElseIf lc > 1 Then
Cells(Target.Row, lc + 1) = Now()
End If
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

[The Image link:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROuWy.png)